# Block a device from outgoing connections to internet (iptables help)

Tags: networking, router, firewall, iptables

I have a router that runs Tomato, so I have access to iptables. There's an IP camera on my network with an IP address of 10.10.2.110 that I want to keep isolated. Based on advice I've read elsewhere, for safety purposes, I should block the camera from making any outgoing connections.  More specifically, this advice I've read mentions that I should do the following to secure my network and camera:

1. Reject all outbound TCP/UDP Connections
2. Drop all outbound connections

I don't know much about iptables so I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  Would anyone be able to help with the iptables commands?

---

I was thinking about something like this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 10.10.2.110 -p udp -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 10.10.2.110 -p tcp -j DROP
```

but I guess this would miss out on the FORWARD command.

Just to understand this a little better, would this work (even if less efficient than your answer)?

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 10.10.2.110 -p udp -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 10.10.2.110 -p tcp -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.10.2.110 -p udp -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.10.2.110 -p tcp -j DROP
```

Comment: `-I INPUT 1 -s <ip camera> -o <internet interface> -j DROP` you probably would want to go for something like this. It would try to insert a rule as the first/second (not sure if counting from 0) on your Input chain and would take traffic from the IP cam that is headed towards the internet and drop it.

Comment: @JoeBob  Expanding on edit.  without the **-o eth0** it blocks **ALL** traffic, even local traffic.  Your camera will be unreachable.  When traffic has to move from one interface say eth0 to eth1 it is consider forwarding, and without the **FORWARD** the rules may do nothing from the internet side.

Answer (score 0):

In my example eth0 is internet

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -s 10.10.2.110 -o eth0 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 10.10.2.110 -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: JoeBob has added further information which I have edited into their question as it was too long for a comment.